# Detecting Quick Access command state

Tags: delphi, ribbon, windows-ribbon-framework

We have an application that is using [Windows Ribbon Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371191(v=vs.85).aspx) for an UI. The app itself is written in Delphi and uses [Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi](http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml) to interface with the ribbon API.

Our ribbon XML places few commands into the [Quick Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940502(v=vs.85).aspx) toolbar. Use can then remove/add commands either by using the built-in ribbon mechanism (selecting the drop/down button and clicking on a command name) or by selecting `More commands` command which opens the configuration dialog.

[image: Quick Access snapshot]

The problem I've encountered is that I cannot find a way to get the current state of commands in the QA collection (whether they are visible or not).

In the example above (picture) I would like to detect that first five commands are checked and that the last is not so I can prepare the configuration dialog accordingly.

I have no problems enumerating the `IUICollection` and accessing the items stored inside. I can also get the `UI_PKEY_CommandId` for each item. I cannot, however, find a way to read the checked/unchecked state. I tried reading `UI_PKEY_BooleanValue` and `UI_PKEY_Enabled` for all items in the collection, but they do not return that state.

I have also tried to monitor `IUICommandHandler.UpdateProperty` but it doesn't get called when such item is checked/unchecked (except that it is called with the `UI_PKEY_Label` key).

Does ribbon API even support this functionality?

Comment: Just a wild guess: From the Ribbon Delphi tutorials. You can associate each command to a `TAction`. Then you can (hopfully) read the `TAction.Checked` property. check out (FMain.pas TFormMain.CommandCreated): https://github.com/TurboPack/RibbonFramework/tree/master/Samples/Medium%20Level/07%20Text%20Pad%20with%20Action%20List

Comment: No, because that again uses UI_PKEY_BooleanValue query which doesn't work for QAT items.

Comment: Just to be on the same, which version of the Ribbon framework are you using? http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml , v. 1.2? or 2.x?

Comment: Currently version 2.x.